# Java stream - find most frequent element based on a specific field

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a list of `Person` objects, I would like to find the most frequent name in the list, and the frequency, only using java streams. (When there is a tie, return any result)

Currently, my solution uses `groupingBy` and `counting`, then again finding the `max` element in the resulting map.
The current solution makes 2 passes on the input (list/map).
Is it possible to make this a bit more efficient and readable?

```
Person p1 = Person.builder().id("p1").name("Alice").age(1).build();
Person p2 = Person.builder().id("p2").name("Bob").age(2).build();
Person p3 = Person.builder().id("p3").name("Charlie").age(3).build();
Person p4 = Person.builder().id("p4").name("Alice").age(4).build();
List<Person> people = ImmutableList.of(p1, p2, p3, p4);

Map.Entry<String, Long> mostCommonName = people
        .stream()
        .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Person::getName, counting()),
                map -> map.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).orElse(null)
        ));

System.out.println(mostCommonName); // Alice=2
```

Comment: Lets say list of people has 2x Alice and 2x Tom. Do you want to get both those names, only Alice, only Tom, or it doesn't matter which one as long as it is *one of* most repeated ones?

Comment: I can see that solutions could be different for each case, I'd like to explore solution to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are insisting on only using streams then your best bet is likely to have a custom collector that includes the info required to aggregate in a single pass:

```
class MaxNameFinder implements Collector<Person, ?, String> {
    public class Accumulator {
        private final Map<String,Integer> nameFrequency = new HashMap<>();
        private int modeFrequency = 0;
        private String modeName = null;

        public String getModeName() {
            return modeName;
        }

        public void accept(Person person) {
            currentFrequency = frequency.merge(p.getName(), 1, Integer::sum);
            if (currentFrequency > modeFrequency) {
                modeName = person.getName();
                modeFrequency = currentFrequency;
            }
        }

        public Accumulator combine(Accumulator other) {
            other.frequency.forEach((n, f) -> this.frequency.merge(n, f, Integer::sum));
            if (this.frequency.get(other.modeName) > frequency.get(this.modeName))
                modeName = other.modeName;
            modeFrequency = frequency.get(modeName);
            return this;
        };

    }

    public BiConsumer<Accumulator,​Person> accumulator() {
        return Accumulator::accept;
    }

    public Set<Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of(Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT);
    }

    public BinaryOperator<Accumulator> combiner() {
        return Accumulator::combine;
    }

    public Function<Accumulator,String> finisher() {
        return Accumulator::getModeName;
    }

    public Supplier<Accumulator> supplier() {
        return Accumulator::new;
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
people.stream().collect(new MaxNameFinder())
```

which would return a string representing the most common name.

Comment: I am actually aware of this solution, but was wondering if there's anything simpler. I'll think more on it..

Comment: If you want to do it in one pass then you'll need logic to collate frequency data - there's just no way around that. You could do without the combining logic (that's only there to support concurrency) but there's not much else you can do to simplify it. Honestly this isn't really a great use case for streams: they don't add a lot of clarity here.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to squeeze two passes into one using loops and [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function returning the calculated frequency value immediately:

```java
String mostCommonName = null;
int maxFreq = 0;
Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();

for (Person p : people) {
    if (freq.merge(p.getName(), 1, Integer::sum) > maxFreq) {
        maxFreq = freq.get(p.getName());
        mostCommonName = p.getName();
    }
}

System.out.printf("Most common name '%s' occurred %d times.%n", mostCommonName, maxFreq);
```